# bash if then else if back up to two drives

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a BASH script for backups to an external drive. I'd run this script to check which drive is attached, then run rsync. I'm new to BASH, and can't quite figure out it's if then else. Could anyone help? What I was thinking was.

```
If [ /Volumes/Drive_1]
 then
     sudo rsync -avx /Volumes/1/2\ __3__/ /Volumes/Drive_1
 else
     If [ /Volumes/Drive_2]
 then
     sudo rsync -avx /Volumes/1/2\ __3__/ /Volumes/Drive_2
 fi
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of great backup tools/scripts out there, many of which can use `rsync` as backend if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the exactly same thing with multiple paths is often most simply done using a Variable and For

eg

```
# Stores all Paths to BackupPaths
BackupPaths=( "/Path/to/First" "/Path/to/second" .... )

# Iterates for each Path and stores current in volume
# $volume allows for accessing the content of the variable
for volume in "${BackupPaths[@]}"; do
    if [ -d "$volume" ]
    then
        sudo rsync -avx /Volumes/1/2\ __3__/ "$volume"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Using a string in place of an array is evil. What you want to back up the contents of `/Users/Firstname Lastname/back-me-up`? Use a proper array: `BackupPaths=( "/Path/to/First" "/Path/to/second" "/Path/containing whitespace" )`, then: `for volume in "${BackupPaths[@]}"; do rsync ... "$volume"; done` (note the quotes around expansions; they're mandatory to avoid bugs).

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Thank you, you are right of course, forgot about whitespace-handling... Added your hint to the answer

Comment: I did a few further tweaks -- there were still quoting bugs present.

Comment: Thanks again, right of course ...
I'm still a bit of a beginner with (correct) bash i fear ;)

Answer (score 3):

First, it's `if`, not `If` (case matters). To check if a drive exists, you'll need to see if the given string names a directory, so you'll need the `-d` primary.

```
 if [ -d /Volumes/Drive_1 ]
 then
     sudo rsync -avx /Volumes/1/2\ __3__/ /Volumes/Drive_1
 elif [ -d /Volumes/Drive_2 ]
 then
     sudo rsync -avx /Volumes/1/2\ __3__/ /Volumes/Drive_2
 fi
```

The spaces separating `[` and `]` from the code between them are necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I think I was anxious to get posting.

Comment: Although this does answer my question, I think Legionair's post is more of what I intended to use.